# Inject a service into an Ember Object [not an Ember Controller]

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to inject an Ember service into an Ember Object but keep getting the following error:

```
"Assertion Failed: Attempting to lookup an injected property on an
object without a container, ensure that the object was instantiated 
via a container."
```

My code looks essentially something like the following:

```
const Model = Ember.Object.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  destroyRecord() {...},

  serialize() {...},

  deserialize() {...},
});

let newModel = Model.create();
newModel.get('store');
```

**Note**: it does work if I inject the service into a Controller, but not an object.  Haven't had any luck trying to figure out how to register the Object with the Ember container.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It works for an `Ember.Controller` because Ember controls the lifecycle of the object. In short, when Ember needs an instance of a certain controller, it asks the container for one, and the container will provide the instance, initializing if necessary.

What this implies is that for dependency injection to work, you would need to get a new instance of `Model` through the container. Assuming Ember 2.3 because of `getOwner`, and that `this` is somewhere inside the Ember application:

```
let owner = Ember.getOwner(this);
let newModel = owner.lookup('object:model');
newmodel.get('store');
```

You can consult the [`lookup` documentation here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/ContainerProxyMixin.html#method_lookup).

But how to register? Use an application initializer:

```
$ ember generate initializer register-model
```

Then, open up the generated initializer and, assuming that your file is in `app/folder/model.js`, put something like:

```
import Model from 'app-name/folder/model';

export function initialize(application) {
  application.register('object:model', Model);
}

export default {
  name: 'register-model',
  initialize
};
```

You can consult the [`register` documentation here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RegistryProxyMixin.html#method_register).

Hope this is helpful!

Comment: So, to clarify, registering objects not already part of the Ember lifecycle (in my case, models), is done with the initializer.  To retrieve the model class elsewhere in the app, call `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup('object:model')`, yeah?  (the lookup call apparently both retreives the Model class and calls `.create()` on it).  In my case, simply importing at the top of all necessary files via `import Model from 'path/to/model;` worked just as well, as I could still interact with static methods.

Comment: In short, yes. You don't really need to register them unless you want Ember to manage the lifecycle, so `import`ing is fine like you said. If you want to discuss in more detail ping me in the Slack group!

Comment: actually, upon taking another look, I realize simply importing via `import Model from `path/to/model';` w/o doing a lookup from within an already-registered object via `Ember.getOwner(this).lookup(...)` still raises the same error.  Will reach out on Slack once I gather my wits about me.

Answer (score 0):

Well you need to passing in the container instance when you create a instance of your model. The container is accessible in the route, controllers, components with `this.get('controller')`. AFAIK basically anything created with the container gets the container property set. Thats why service injections work in controllers etc..

So if you are creating the model in a route's method. The code will look like below

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    var newModel = Model.create({
      container: this.get('container')
    });    
    return newModel.get('test').getText();
  }
});
```

[**Here is a working demo.**](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/goxuqox/1/edit?html,js,output)