# Inject service into a Ember utility

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

Inject service into a utility Ember-cli ??

I have an Ember utility which makes an ajax call using Ember.$.ajax.
But when I get an unauthorised response from the server I want to invalidate the session.
For that, I need to access Session service which I am unable to access in utility.

In the following link, it tells how to use util inside service not service inside util
https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.12.0/tutorial/service/

Comment: Refer this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34971940/5771666 it has excellent explanation. try it out and post your attempt with error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add Ember application to window scope using initializer:

   a) Generate initializer using Ember CLI:

   ```
   ember generate initializer global-app
   ```

   b) In generated initializer:

   ```
   export function initialize(application) {
     window.AppContainer = application;
   }

   export default {
     name: 'global-app',
     initialize
   };
   ```
2. Then you can find your service in AppContainer from utils methods:

```
     const session = window.AppContainer.lookup('service:session');
     session.invalidate();
```

Comment: My Ember util is a function.
I am getting following error - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookup' of undefined

Comment: @LakhanBaheti, which version of Ember do you use?

Comment: @LakhanBaheti, Ember app should be added to global scope via inititalizer. I've updated my initial answer.